# Why is my shell changing when I use 'sudo'?

Tags: macos, shell, heroku

When I run `sudo su` on my mac os x (10.8.5) MacBook Air, the shell changes for some reason:

```
bos-mp2o6:~ rabdelaz$ sudo su
Password: 
sh-3.2#
```

What's up with that?

The only thing I've done is install Heroku Toolbelt and, after getting `sudo: unable to cache user root, already exists`, rebooting.

Comment: When you use `sudo su`, it runs the superuser's `.bashrc`, so you get its prompt instead of your own.

Comment: @Barmar you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `sudo su`, it runs the superuser's `.bashrc`, so you get its prompt instead of your own.